# Need some advice on Big Data ETL job cost effective design

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, bigdata, amazon-emr

I need some advice on designing a big data ETL job that processes hourly/daily. I need a system that runs periodically over 1.8TB metadata to transform the data into a billing report for downstream usage.

Requirements:

```
Primary DataSource: DynamoDB has the core metadata, 1.8TB and growing unbounded, metadata would be updated all the time.

Latency: Need to finish the job within 12 hours.

Availability: Critical business logic is running on the DDB tables, I cannot afford to impact business when trying to run the ETL job to produce billing reports.
```

I am looking into the AWS EMR, but I could not find a cost effective way to dump the DDB data into EMR, even if I am dumping daily, scan through the entire table each time end up costing $60000:

```
1 RCU would be 4KB:
1.8TB * 1024^3 / 4 = 483183820.8 * (0.00013/RCU) = $62813
```

Given the size of the data, my initial thought is to dump the data daily as a snapshot and compute the hourly business report of the previous day. But still, doing a daily dump would come down to an overwhelming $2M every month.

Could I get some advice on cost effective way for this job?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to dump data on EMR? You just need to run your compute on EMR, your source can still be dynamodb.

For the first iteration, just read all the data present in dynamodb and create your report. From next iteration onwards, just read the delta from dynamodb and update your report.